# Changing to Spanish language on Windows Vista Business

Tags: windows, windows-vista, language

My school is taking some donated laptops from the United States on a mission trip to Peru. These computers are all running Windows Vista Business in English. We need to switch these computers to use Spanish. I have not been successful in installing the Spanish Language Interface Pack (LIP), and according to [the Microsoft website](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/language-packs#lptabs=vista), it looks like even the Spanish LIP might require Windows Vista Ultimate.

Is there a way to switch these computers to Spanish on Windows Vista Business edition?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change system language from Russian to English in Vista](http://superuser.com/questions/22014/change-system-language-from-russian-to-english-in-vista), also see [Can I change Windows 7 display language on Home Premium version?](http://superuser.com/questions/77166/can-i-change-windows-7-display-language-on-home-premium-version?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with Vista Business. The Home and Business Editions are single language editions, where you can't install a new MUI. You need the Enterprise or Ultimate Edition.

To change the language you need to reinstall the Windows and use a Spanish Vista DVD/ISO.

Comment: Followup question: would the product keys from the bottom of the laptops work with another language edition?

Comment: the product key works with all languages.